# The result appears like a LOOP

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I need some help. I am stuck in a while loop when I display the result. Let me show you the code, the inputs and the results.

This is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = scanner.nextInt();

    int[] array = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    int x = scanner.nextInt();

    int[] sortedArray = sortedArray(array);

    int st = 0;
    int dr = n - 1;
    int ok = 0;
    int mij;

    while (st <= dr && ok == 0) {
        mij = (st + dr) / 2;
        if (sortedArray[mij] == x) {
            System.out.println(sortedArray[mij]);
            ok = 1;
        } else {
            if (x > sortedArray[mij]) {
                if((dr - mij) % 2 != 0){
                    st = mij + 1;
                } else {
                    st = mij;
                }

            } else if (x < sortedArray[mij]) {
                if((mij - st) % 2 != 0) {
                    dr = mij - 1;
                } else {
                    dr = mij;
                }

            }
            System.out.println(sortedArray[mij]);
        }
    }
}


public static int[] sortedArray(int[] array) {
    int[] sortedArray = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
        sortedArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < sortedArray.length; j++) {
            if (sortedArray[i] > sortedArray[j]) {
                temp = sortedArray[i];
                sortedArray[i] = sortedArray[j];
                sortedArray[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return sortedArray;
}
```

}

This are the inputs: 
    11
    20
    40
    11
    54
    100
    56
    67
    45
    24
    21
    78
    50`

This are the results:
    `45
    67
    56
    54
    54
    54
    54
    54
    54
    54
    54
    54
    54`

So you can see that 54 appear in a continuous loop. I think that is while fault. The results are good but I need to escape from this loop for the last result (54).

P.S. This is not the entire code, if you need more I will post it here. Thanks!

Comment: Showing more code would be helpful

Comment: We have no idea what variable contains what, and your variable names don't really make it easy to "follow" the flow without more context.

Comment: "_P.S. This is not the entire code, if you need more I will post it here_" we mostly need [mcve], not the entire code, just a snippet that show exactly what is going on.

Comment: Please post the initialisation of the variables that are used in this code snippet. Don't post your whole program though.
**YOU SHOULD ALWAYS USE MEANINGFUL NAMING FOR YOUR VARIABLES. PLEASE REFER TO [CODING CONVENTIONS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions) FOR EXAMPLES**

Comment: Ok. I edited the code. I have an array and I must do a kind of binary search. "st" actually means left and is the first position in the sortedArray and "dr" means right and is the last position in the array. "n" is the elements number of the array and "x" is a value that compares the mean of the vector. If x > the mean value from array, I will have a right sub-array or x < the mean value, I will have a left sub-array. First I will display the mean value from the array, after I will do the same for the sub array.

Comment: A debugger will show you what's wrong, but basically after a few iterations, `dr` and `mij` are both `6` and it goes to `else` in your `else if`, assigns `dr` to `mij` (which obviously doesn't matter as they're both the same value), and then returns to top of while loop. Oh `st` is also `6` at this point. Meaningless variable names make it harder for others to read your code, as mentioned above already.

Comment: One example: x = 50, n = 11; array=[20 40 11 54 100 56 67 45 24 21 78]; sortedArray = [11 20 21 24 40 45 54 56 67 78 100]; 
P1: Array=[11 20 21 24 40 45 54 56 67 78 100]; middle = 45; (index = 5)
P2: x > middle => subArray = [ 54 56 67 78 100]; middle = 67; (index = 2)
P3: x < middle => subArray = [54 56], but because are two values and doesn't exist a middle we must to add the middle value to the last position => 
=> subArray = [54, 56, 67]; middle = 56 (index = 1)
P4: x < middle => subArray = [54] ; midle = 54 (index = 0);
sout: 45, 67, 56, 54

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try to make your code better, *(even though it can be rewritten to be much much more efficient)*, but I tried to make it more readable and fix your error. I haven't tested it, but I think it should work correctly now.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arraySize = scanner.nextInt();

    int[] array = new int[arraySize];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    int requestedNumber = scanner.nextInt();

    int[] sortedArray = sortedArray(array);
    int left = 0;
    int right = arraySize-1;
    int i;

    while(true)
    {
        i = (left + right) / 2;
        if (sortedArray[i] == requestedNumber)
        {
            System.out.println("Found requested element -> "+array[i]);
            break;
        }
        else if(i == left || i == right)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not find requested element -> "+requestedNumber);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (requestedNumber > sortedArray[i])
            {
                if ((right - i) % 2 != 0)
                    left = i + 1;
                else
                    left = i;
            }
            else if (requestedNumber < sortedArray[i])
            {
                if ((i - left) % 2 != 0)
                {
                    right = i - 1;
                }
                else
                    right = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sortedArray[i]);
    }
```

**NOTE: the variable *"ok"* (Integer) that you use as a terminating condition to your loop, is 100% unnecessary for the code you provided, but if you absolutely have to use a terminating condition, consider using a Boolean!**

Comment: I edited the code and it still make that loop for the last result.

Comment: Whoops, looks like my carelessness is to blame! It's stuck into a loop, because instead of checking if **index** is equal to *left* or *right*, I just check for *0* and *final element*. I just updated the correct answer. Please consider checking this as an accepted solution to your question. I **TESTED** this, and it works. Even though it is not the best way to do a binary search